# Replace Brunch with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, brunch

I am working on a project which uses Brunch to compile and minify js/css files. The site is a bit slow and I want that I may use `requirejs as the AMD module, replacing Brunch`. 
Will it have a reasonable effect on that?

Answer (score 2):

Brunch is a web app build tool, not a module system. Brunch provides an option to wrap your modules with AMD-style definitions.

From https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md#modules:

```
# To use AMD, just add this and add require.js as
# your first vendor file.
modules:
  wrapper: 'amd'
  definition: 'amd'
```

Comment: Do you have any working example or a fiddle where it can be seen?

Comment: I can't vouch for it, but a quick search yielded this example: https://github.com/rauluranga/SimpleBrunch